# Recurrent Variable in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm working on a database which has information about individual identification (`Id`), `Date`, `Group_id`

```
data = data.frame(Id = 1:6, 
                  Date = as.Date(c("2010-12-28", "2011-01-28", "2011-01-30", "2009-09-01", "2009-09-05", "2012-12-20")), 
                  Group_id = c(1,1,2,3,3,3))
```

and now I would like to create a new dummy `Recurrent` variable that returns 1 if there are previous information about another individual from the same `Group_id` and 0 otherwise . My desired output is like this:

```
Id      Date      Group_id  Recurrent
1      2010-12-28    1          0
2      2011-01-28    1          1
3      2011-01-30    2          0
4      2009-09-01    3          0
5      2009-09-05    3          1
6      2012-12-20    3          1
```

but I'm quite confused about how to perform that. Can anyone give me a tip on how to do that?

regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try this

```
library(dplyr)

data |> mutate(Recurrent = as.numeric(duplicated(Group_id)))
```

- Output

```
 Id       Date Group_id Recurrent
1  1 2010-12-28        1         0
2  2 2011-01-28        1         1
3  3 2011-01-30        2         0
4  4 2009-09-01        3         0
5  5 2009-09-05        3         1
6  6 2012-12-20        3         1
```